# Work Item Template: On closing a task validate that the Remaining Field is Zero or Empty

Tags: tfs, tfs-workitem

In TFS (2014) I am wanting to update the WIT Template so that when change a Task from "Active" to "Closed" it will Check the "Remaining" Field has been changed to 0 (or Empty) and that there is a value in completed of either 0 or above.

Is there a way to have some validation giving a message such as "Please update Remaining field before saving"?

I'm assuming that it is something that needs changing in this section

```
<TRANSITION from="Active" to="Closed">
  <REASONS>
    <DEFAULTREASON value="Completed" />
    <REASON value="Deferred" />
    <REASON value="Obsolete" />
    <REASON value="Cut" />
  </REASONS>
  <FIELDS>
    <FIELD refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Common.ActivatedDate">
      <READONLY />
    </FIELD>
    <FIELD refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Common.ActivatedBy">
      <ALLOWEXISTINGVALUE />
      <READONLY />
    </FIELD>
    <FIELD refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Common.ClosedDate">
      <SERVERDEFAULT from="clock" />
    </FIELD>
    <FIELD refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Common.ClosedBy">
      <ALLOWEXISTINGVALUE />
      <COPY from="currentuser" />
      <VALIDUSER />
      <REQUIRED />
    </FIELD>
  </FIELDS>
</TRANSITION>
```

Note:
I dont want it to automatically change the value to zero / Empty like article
[TFS2012 Task work item definition - Update 'Remaining Work' with 'Original Estimate' whenever 'Remaining Work' is empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21575332/tfs2012-task-work-item-definition-update-remaining-work-with-original-estim)

Comment: After having a bit more of a look around I have found some articles

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sunder/archive/2009/04/24/work-item-rules-workaround-cannot-close-task-unless-remaining-work-is-zero.aspx

For some reason this does not currently work in Web Access. I am going to raise a Microsoft connect issue.

Comment: I have raised this Microsoft but after rebooting my machine it seems to be working on web access now.